# Adjustable Fortran Arrays with F2PY

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I have been attempting to wrap some Fortran libraries and enhance some routines to allow them to utilize numpy arrays of inputs and outputs rather than a single input and output.  For the most part I have been successful and have wrapped a few simple routines.  The only problem has been my f_prog routine.

```
subroutine f_prog(mu,x,y,m)
    integer :: m, i
    !f2py intent(hide) :: m
    DOUBLE PRECISION, intent(in) :: mu
    DOUBLE PRECISION, dimension(m , 6), intent(in) :: x
    DOUBLE PRECISION, dimension(m , 6), intent(out) :: y
    DOUBLE PRECISION, dimension( 6 ) :: y_temp(6)
    do i=1,m
        call prog(mu,x(i,1:6),y_temp)   
        y(i,1:6)=y_temp(1:6)
    enddo   
end subroutine
```

When running f_prog with the inputs *f_prog( 1 , ([1,2,3,4,5,6]) )* I recieve the error:

```
    In [21]: clout(gm[0],sc_mars[0])
    1-th dimension must be 6 but got 0 (not defined).
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    error                                    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-21-1614a809900e> in <module>()
    ----> 1 clout(gm[0],sc_mars[0])

    error: failed in converting 2nd argument `x' of pythage_new.f_clout to C/Fortran array
```

but when i run it using *f_prog( 1 , ([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]) )* I recieve my expected output.  Note that all array inputs use the Numpy library in Python and are not Python's standard list structures.

The error leads me to believe that F2PY is not respecting the dimensions of the array when it is only a single row.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

As Warren mentioned below, it is also possible to nest the arrays as such:

```
f_prog( 1 , [[1,2,3,4,5,6]] )
```

Although, I am trying to create a standard library so forcing the user to add brackets around a variable every time they want to use this routine isn't very practical.

Comment: Please always use tag [tag:fortran], fortra90 is only as an additional distinction and is unnecessary here (if not harmful). Your title speaks about *allocatable* arrays, but I can't find any allocatable array in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to the use of Stack Overflow!  I didn't really have an idea how to title this.  I've changed the title to better reflect what I'm doing.  F2PY doesn't support true allocatable arrays so I have to work around it in some respects.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I get your problem. Especially what you mean by adjustable or allocatable or dynamically sized arrays here. There is no dynamic change of any array in your code. The F2py subroutine just accepts some array, it doesn't matter how it emerged, it just have to have the correct size 6 in the second dimension.

You also say you are using NumPy arrays, but there are no numpy arrays in your code. If you want to use numpy arrays, then just create one:

```
#create a Numpy array in Fortran ordering
arr = numpy.zeros([3,6], order='F')

#fill in some values
arr[:,:] = numpy.random.rand(3,6)

#run your f2py code
f_prog.f_prog(1, arr)
```

---

If you need to input a vector, you should reshape it it to be viewed as a 2D array, because the subroutine needs a 2D array

```
f_prog.f_prog(1, numpy.reshape([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.], [1,6],order='F'))
```

Comment: As this is part of a set of library routines, it is only a small part of a larger program.  I define the arrays elsewhere in a python script.  The variable "m" above is input as the number of rows in both the input and output arrays (so i dont have to initialize large arrays of zeros).  The best way I could describe arrays with variable sizes being input into this Python routine was calling it "adjustable".  The specific problem that I am having isnt creating the arrays.  Its that when I input a vector I get an error, but when I use an array of vectors it works fine.

Comment: See the edit, just reshape the list or a 1D array. If you don't want to do that, you should create a new version, which accepts 1D arrays and call the old one from there. Or make a Python function, which does the reshape for you and which calls the old version for 2D.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I have been trying to pass multi-dimensional array to Fortran and turns out `order = 'F'` is the key here!

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `f_prog( 1 , ([1,2,3,4,5,6]) )`, the parentheses around `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` have *no effect* (just like `(1)` is the same thing as `1`), so the argument is a one-dimensional sequence.  To make it something that looks like a 2-d sequence, you can add a trailing comma so that it is a tuple containing a list: `f_prog(1, ([1,2,3,4,5,6],))`.  Or use nested lists: `f_prog(1, [[1,2,3,4,5,6]])`.

*Update*: The problem (as I understand it now) is that the wrapper that f2py generates is pickier about the shape of the arguments than you would like it to be.  The Fortran file says that the arguments are 2-d, so f2py insists that the user call the function with 2-d numpy arrays.  This is easy enough to do, but it would be nice if a user of the function could also pass in a 1-d array, and have the code treat it as a 2-d array containing a single row.

A possible work-around is to create a thin wrapper around the f2py function.  In the wrapper, call `atleast_2d` on the array argument before passing it to the f2py function.  Roughly something like this:

```
def func(mu, x):
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    y = f_prog(mu, x)  # Call the function that was generated by f2py.
    return y
```

Comment: The parentheses that I have placed around the array are an artifact of the way Python's Numpy library holds and displays arrays. If i have a standard Numpy array holding values in the manner described above I get this issue. I don't want to have to modify my arrays every time in this way if I don't have to.  I apologize as it seems I did not originally mention I was using Numpy arrays.